# Cannot change admin account password on company-provided laptop

Tags: macos, password, administrator, active-directory, kerberos

I have a macbook pro running macOS Big Sur 11.1 that was given to me by my former employer. They allowed me to keep the laptop after I left the company. When I try changing my password, I get this error:

[image]

I understand that my company's network administration setup still has its tentacles in my machine. This is the output from `klist`:

```
Credentials cache: API:9F3BD780-2620-4574-A37D-C745AC9FBCA5
        Principal: my.username@company.domain.name

  Issued    Expires    Principal
```

How do I change my password?

Comment: Sign out from the Open Directory server?

Comment: You have to contact your company and ask them to remove that system from their MDM software, effectively then unlocking that Mac and and giving you the rights to do as you please with that Mac. Without that you are permanently locked out.